# Wordpress создания своего мета поля для записи массива картинок, как?)

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Здравствуйте друзья, есть допустим свой тип записи, или основной, это не суть. Нужно добавить в него поле которое будет писать массив изображений загруженных пользователем (через интерфйс админки). В общем то это вся задача )

UPD Отметили что требует правки, попробую дополнить

```html
 
function my_meta_box() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'my_meta_box', 
        'My Meta Box', 
        'show_my_metabox', 
        'post', 
        'normal',
        'high');
}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_meta_box'); 
 
$meta_fields = array(  
    array(  
        'label' => 'Галерея',  
        'desc'  => '',  
        'id'    => 'price', 
        'type'  => 'text'  // ??
    )
```

В общем стандартный код создания своего поля для ввода данных. 
Нужно сделать так что бы это поле принимало масиив из ссылок на картинки вставленных пользователем через стандартный интерфейс WP для работы с медифайлами.
Собственно интересует как это сделать.

UPD2 Возможно это как то можно реализовать через стандартную работу с галереями wp [gallery ids="1,2,3"] - это же массив и можно его забрать в виде массива для темизации вывода? Только нужно что бы этот массив писался в отдельную переменную в отдельном поле.

Comment: Я так понимаю автора интересует возможность реализации такого же функционала как в плагине woocommerce, где для товара есть возможность добавить картинки в галерею через библиотеку медиафайлов. Сам задумывался над такой возможностью, но пока руки недошли заняться этим вопросом. Было бы интересно, если кто то ответит.

Answer (score 1):

В общем варианта решения задачи три:

1) Поставить Visuаl Composer и вставить галерею
Из минусов - тяжел в работе, плохо масштабируем.

2) ACF плагин.
Покупаете и вставляете поля галерея и добавляете в админке и в коде
Из минусов - надо кодить.
Вот пример использования:

- https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/e1d39ae81ab2abcb4dbcb0fbffc00b81

3) Использовать штатные кастомные поля и виджеты  в комбинации с шоткодами

- https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F
- https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/kak-sozdat-svoy-vidzhet-v-wordpress/
- https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/265245/